# Run main file in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tablesaw

In Intellij there is no Run button when click right mouse button. I try to add new configuration as "new application" but file which I want to run go grey in settings. This file is example of tablesaw-jsplot which include main method.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on src -> Mark Directory As -> Sources Root